# Provide a payment option

Tags: meaning

For example a firm provide his customer to make payment 30 days after buying without charging interest . In this case can I say sentence below to describe this situation and are word orders correct? I know it is hard to understand but As I am not native speaker I have to make sentence with my limited information. I just wonder if I grammatically describe this situation with these sentences.

> 1) There is a option in the  firm A which provides customer to make payment 30 days after buying without paying interest.
>
> 2) There is a option of payment deferred for 30 days without interest in the firm A.
>
> 3)There is a payment option which will be made after 30 days after buying without interest in the firm A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the word “defer” is good, but there are multiple errors in all three sentences. These include:

1. The use of the preposition “in” is incorrect in the phrases: “an option in the firm A“ and “without interest in the firm A”. Both fail to indicate that the firm is *offering* an option of no interest and instead  the wording suggests that options and interest are ”within” the firm somehow.
2. Starting with “There is an option...” makes for awkward reading from the outset. I’d expect something like:

> “You may choose to defer payment...”
>
> ”Customers can defer payment...”
>
> “Payment may be deferred for 30 days...”

3. Mentioning the name of the firm in such sentences seems irrelevant and forced. Surely the context makes it clear which business is offering to defer payment interest free for 30 days. For example:

> ```
> ORBITAL APPLIANCES - Terms of Sale
> ```
>
> We offer generous terms. Customers may defer payment for up to 30 days interest-free. After 30 days, interest is payable on any outstanding balances at a rate of...

Comment: Thank you so much . Is the word order of phrase “  a option of payment deferred for 30 days without interest ” correct ?

Comment: The word order is not really the issue - the word choice is not correct. The closest correct paraphrase might be, “AN option FOR payment IS TO defer IT for 30 days without interest”

Answer (score -1):

It should read
There is an interest-free deferred payment option which allows the customer to pay 30 days after purchase.